# How do you add multiple filter values when using a Query String (URL) Filter web part on a SharePoint Online classic page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, query-string

I have a Query String (URL) Filter web part on my SharePoint Online classic page. I want to filter for multiple values and can't determined how to do this. I have appended the following with no success:

?Capabilities=DDS --yields the expected DDS results

?Capabilities=DDS&Capabilities=Equity --yields only DDS results

?Capabilities=DDS;Equity --yields no results

?Capabilities=DDS;#Equity --yields no results

Does anyone know how I can have multiples filter values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To apply multiple filter values to a single column, please use this syntax:

?&FilterName=Capabilities&FilterMultiValue=DDS;Equity

Comment: The appended syntax doesn't trigger filtering of the column.